# nhibernate named query join single record

Tags: nhibernate, join, named-query

This is what i have:

```
class Unit
{
   public Position ManagerPosition;
}

<sql-query name="GetUnits" read-only="true">
    <query-param name="UserGroupId" type="int"/>
    <query-param name="RelevantToDate" type="datetime"/>
    <query-param name="ParentUnitId" type="int"/>

    <return class="Unit" />
...
</sql-query>

<sql-query name="GetPositions" read-only="true">
    <query-param name="UserGroupId" type="int"/>
    <query-param name="RelevantToDate" type="datetime"/>
    <query-param name="UnitId" type="int"/>
    <query-param name="ManagersOnly" type="bool"/>

    <return class="Position" />
...
</sql-query>
```

**Units** and **Positions** are in separate tables, but both filtered by **UserGroupId** and **RelevantDate** (the parameters of the appropriate named queries). they are not mapped to the tables directly because of the complexity of their properties.

What i'm trying to do is to get a list of **Units** with a single **Position** which has its flag **IsManager** set to **True**.

I've tried to do it by return-join - no success.
I've tried to do it by

```
<return class="Unit">
  <return-property name="ManagerialPosition" column="position"/>
</return>
```

and

```
<return alias="position" class="Position">
```

but the NHibernate said that it can't cast an array of System.Object to an array of Unit.

**what is better way to solve my problem?** thanks in advance!

the preferable ways are:

1. call a parameterized query for Position from Unit query.
2. parse a resultset of a combined query to get Unit and Position properties

Comment: Can you solve your own problem by writing an SQL-statement for it?